# Why is Liquibase throwing this error: Could not parse a SqlCheck precondition

Tags: liquibase

I'm trying to add preconditions to a SQL formatted changeset in Liquibase 3.1.1

```
--preconditions onFail=HALT onError=HALT
--precondition-sql-check expectedResult=0 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_ERRORS WHERE TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
--changeset myteam:101 runAlways:true
```

Liquibase raises this error when I run a status:

```
Liquibase status Failed: Could not parse a SqlCheck precondition from 'expectedResult=0 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_ERRORS WHERE TYPE = '
PROCEDURE''.
```

What's wrong with that precondition syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There needs to be a colon instead of an equals char after "expectedResult".

So the line should be:

```
--precondition-sql-check expectedResult:0 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_ERRORS WHERE TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
```

Then it should work.

**EDIT:** *(Documentation was updated. See Nathans comment.)*

<s>This is also wrong on the liquibase documentation for the [Formatted SQL Changelogs](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_format.html).</s>